# Custom function returning crazy output when assigned to reactiveValue

Tags: r, shiny

My mind is boggled by the output from a custom function I wrote to read in different kinds of data depending on the file name. I am planning on using UI inputs in a Shiny App to process the data, but I've hit this snag and I have no idea why it is not working since I have used this workflow of uploading data using fileInput many times. Here is my app.R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(DT)

source("global.R")

ui <- page_sidebar(
  sidebar = sidebar(
    fileInput("data_file", "Upload Cast Data", accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls", ".txt")),
    
  ),
  navset_card_underline(
    nav_panel("Raw Data",
              renderDataTable("raw_datatable"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  origin <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$data_file, {
    browser()
    data <- read_depth_data(input$data_file$datapath)
    
    origin$data <- data
  })
  
  output$raw_datatable <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$data_file)
    origin$data %>%
      datatable()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is the custom function `read_depth_data`:

```
read_depth_data <- function(datapath){
  if(grepl("EXO", datapath, ignore.case = T)){
    data <- read.csv(datapath, skip = 9, header = F) %>%
      select(V1, V2, V8, V20, V12, V5, V9, V11, V14, V17)
    
    names(data) <- c("Date", "Time", "Depth", "Temp", "PSI", "Chla", "DOsat", "DO", "SpCond", "Turbidity")
    
  } else if(grepl("fpprofile", datapath, ignore.case = T)){
    
    data <- read.table(datapath, sep = "\t", skip = 2, 
                       col.names = c("DateTime", "Greens", "Cyano", "Diatoms", "Crypto", 
                                     "#5", "#6", "#7", "Yellow", "totChla", "Transmission",
                                     "Depth", "Temp", "GreenCells", "CyanoCells", "DiatomCells", 
                                     "CryptoCells", "#5cells", "#6cells", "#7cells", "Yellow2", 
                                     "totCellCt", "T700", "LED3", "LED4", "LED5", "LED6", "LED7", 
                                     "LED8", "Pressure", "TLED", "TSensor"),
                       colClasses = c("character", rep("numeric", 4), rep("NULL", 3), rep("numeric", 5), rep("NULL", 16), "numeric", "NULL", "NULL")) %>%
      relocate(Depth, Temp, Pressure, .after = DateTime)
  }
  return(data)
}
```

When I try to look at the raw uploaded data, nothing appears, so I inserted the `browser()` to see what was going wrong, and when I look at the value of `data` in the observeEvent` it is this crazy function:

```
function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, 
  verbose = getOption("verbose"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) 
{
  fileExt <- function(x) {
    db <- grepl("\\.[^.]+\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$", x)
    ans <- sub(".*\\.", "", x)
    ans[db] <- sub(".*\\.([^.]+\\.)(gz|bz2|xz)$", "\\1\\2", 
      x[db])
    ans
  }
  my_read_table <- function(...) {
    lcc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
    on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", lcc))
    Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
    read.table(...)
  }
  stopifnot(is.character(list))
  names <- c(as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1L]), list)
  if (!is.null(package)) {
    if (!is.character(package)) 
      stop("'package' must be a character vector or NULL")
  }
  paths <- find.package(package, lib.loc, verbose = verbose)
  if (is.null(lib.loc)) 
    paths <- c(path.package(package, TRUE), if (!length(package)) getwd(), 
      paths)
  paths <- unique(normalizePath(paths[file.exists(paths)]))
  paths <- paths[dir.exists(file.path(paths, "data"))]
  dataExts <- tools:::.make_file_exts("data")
  if (length(names) == 0L) {
    db <- matrix(character(), nrow = 0L, ncol = 4L)
    for (path in paths) {
      entries <- NULL
      packageName <- if (file_test("-f", file.path(path, 
        "DESCRIPTION"))) 
        basename(path)
      else "."
      if (file_test("-f", INDEX <- file.path(path, "Meta", 
        "data.rds"))) {
        entries <- readRDS(INDEX)
      }
      else {
        dataDir <- file.path(path, "data")
        entries <- tools::list_files_with_type(dataDir, 
          "data")
        if (length(entries)) {
          entries <- unique(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(entries)))
          entries <- cbind(entries, "")
        }
      }
      if (NROW(entries)) {
        if (is.matrix(entries) && ncol(entries) == 2L) 
          db <- rbind(db, cbind(packageName, dirname(path), 
            entries))
        else warning(gettextf("data index for package %s is invalid and will be ignored", 
          sQuote(packageName)), domain = NA, call. = FALSE)
      }
    }
    colnames(db) <- c("Package", "LibPath", "Item", "Title")
    footer <- if (missing(package)) 
      paste0("Use ", sQuote(paste("data(package =", ".packages(all.available = TRUE))")), 
        "\n", "to list the data sets in all *available* packages.")
    else NULL
    y <- list(title = "Data sets", header = NULL, results = db, 
      footer = footer)
    class(y) <- "packageIQR"
    return(y)
  }
  paths <- file.path(paths, "data")
  for (name in names) {
    found <- FALSE
    for (p in paths) {
      tmp_env <- if (overwrite) 
        envir
      else new.env()
      if (file_test("-f", file.path(p, "Rdata.rds"))) {
        rds <- readRDS(file.path(p, "Rdata.rds"))
        if (name %in% names(rds)) {
          found <- TRUE
          if (verbose) 
            message(sprintf("name=%s:\t found in Rdata.rds", 
              name), domain = NA)
          thispkg <- sub(".*/([^/]*)/data$", "\\1", 
            p)
          thispkg <- sub("_.*$", "", thispkg)
          thispkg <- paste0("package:", thispkg)
          objs <- rds[[name]]
          lazyLoad(file.path(p, "Rdata"), envir = tmp_env, 
            filter = function(x) x %in% objs)
          break
        }
        else if (verbose) 
          message(sprintf("name=%s:\t NOT found in names() of Rdata.rds, i.e.,\n\t%s\n", 
            name, paste(names(rds), collapse = ",")), 
            domain = NA)
      }
      if (file_test("-f", file.path(p, "Rdata.zip"))) {
        warning("zipped data found for package ", sQuote(basename(dirname(p))), 
          ".\nThat is defunct, so please re-install the package.", 
          domain = NA)
        if (file_test("-f", fp <- file.path(p, "filelist"))) 
          files <- file.path(p, scan(fp, what = "", 
            quiet = TRUE))
        else {
          warning(gettextf("file 'filelist' is missing for directory %s", 
            sQuote(p)), domain = NA)
          next
        }
      }
      else {
        files <- list.files(p, full.names = TRUE)
      }
      files <- files[grep(name, files, fixed = TRUE)]
      if (length(files) > 1L) {
        o <- match(fileExt(files), dataExts, nomatch = 100L)
        paths0 <- dirname(files)
        paths0 <- factor(paths0, levels = unique(paths0))
        files <- files[order(paths0, o)]
      }
      if (length(files)) {
        for (file in files) {
          if (verbose) 
            message("name=", name, ":\t file= ...", 
              .Platform$file.sep, basename(file), "::\t", 
              appendLF = FALSE, domain = NA)
          ext <- fileExt(file)
          if (basename(file) != paste0(name, ".", ext)) 
            found <- FALSE
          else {
            found <- TRUE
            zfile <- file
            zipname <- file.path(dirname(file), "Rdata.zip")
            if (file.exists(zipname)) {
              Rdatadir <- tempfile("Rdata")
              dir.create(Rdatadir, showWarnings = FALSE)
              topic <- basename(file)
              rc <- .External(C_unzip, zipname, topic, 
                Rdatadir, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
              if (rc == 0L) 
                zfile <- file.path(Rdatadir, topic)
            }
            if (zfile != file) 
              on.exit(unlink(zfile))
            switch(ext, R = , r = {
              library("utils")
              sys.source(zfile, chdir = TRUE, envir = tmp_env)
            }, RData = , rdata = , rda = load(zfile, 
              envir = tmp_env), TXT = , txt = , tab = , 
              tab.gz = , tab.bz2 = , tab.xz = , txt.gz = , 
              txt.bz2 = , txt.xz = assign(name, my_read_table(zfile, 
                header = TRUE, as.is = FALSE), envir = tmp_env), 
              CSV = , csv = , csv.gz = , csv.bz2 = , 
              csv.xz = assign(name, my_read_table(zfile, 
                header = TRUE, sep = ";", as.is = FALSE), 
                envir = tmp_env), found <- FALSE)
          }
          if (found) 
            break
        }
        if (verbose) 
          message(if (!found) 
            "*NOT* ", "found", domain = NA)
      }
      if (found) 
        break
    }
    if (!found) {
      warning(gettextf("data set %s not found", sQuote(name)), 
        domain = NA)
    }
    else if (!overwrite) {
      for (o in ls(envir = tmp_env, all.names = TRUE)) {
        if (exists(o, envir = envir, inherits = FALSE)) 
          warning(gettextf("an object named %s already exists and will not be overwritten", 
            sQuote(o)))
        else assign(o, get(o, envir = tmp_env, inherits = FALSE), 
          envir = envir)
      }
      rm(tmp_env)
    }
  }
  invisible(names)
}
```

How is this happening? I originally called the custom function `read_data`, and I thought maybe there was a conflict happenning somewhere, but I restarted R and the problem persisted after renaming the function to `read_depth_data`. Any insight would be great. I can't provide sample data of stuff I am trying to upload, but they are simple .txt or .csv files from lab instruments that I have used many times before. I have no idea where this large function is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This is because "data" is a base R function in utils package: see `?data`
And in your code you have defined the variable "data" local to the if/else statement, but not local to the function itself.  So when you `return(data)` you  are in fact returning utils::data function and not your variable data.

Try this instead (shortened to focus on the essence):

```
read_depth_data <- function(datapath){
  data <- NULL #here data variable is now defined within the function scope
  if(grepl("EXO", datapath, ignore.case = T)){
    data <- read.csv() 
    
  } else if(grepl("fpprofile", datapath, ignore.case = T)){
    
    data <- read.table()
  }
  return(data)
}
```